# How can I pass two variables from two combo box to a sub?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two combo box. each combo box results in a variable. I want to pass these two variables (wc1 and wc2) to another sub.
My code doesn't work.

```
Public Sub ComboBox1_Change()
      wc1 = Sheets("Book1").Cells(1, 3).Address()
End Sub
Public Sub ComboBox2_Change()
      wc2 = Sheets("Book1").Cells(2, 3).Address()
End Sub
Public Sub thirdf()
 Dim tval As String
   Set lola = Sheets("Book1").Range(wc1 & ":" & wc2)
     For Each cel In lola
       tval = tval & cel.Value
         Next
           Cells(1, 7).Value = tval

 End Sub
```

Comment: What are wc1, wc2? Combo boxes? String Variables?

Comment: They are address and are used in Sub thirdf(). For example wc1 may be $A$1

Answer (score 0):

Based on javad's comment, delete the Address methods and use Range(wc1, wc2).

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  thirdf Sheets("Book1").Cells(1, 3).Address,Sheets("Book1").Cells(2, 3).Address
End Sub

Public Sub ComboBox2_Change()
  thirdf Sheets("Book1").Cells(1, 3).Address,Sheets("Book1").Cells(2, 3).Address
End Sub

Public Sub thirdf(c00,c01)
  For Each cl Sheets("Book1").Range(c00 &":" & c01)
   tval = tval & cl.Value
  Next
  sheets("Book1").Cells(1, 7).Value = tval
End Sub
```